# WordPress image post and gallery post issue

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add image post format in WordPress. If the user does not upload a featured image but adds images in the body, I want to grab the first image from the attachments and show it as the top header image and the rest in the article body. Here is the function I came up with. Works if featured image is uploaded but if not, it grabs an image which is not even in the body of the post. Looks like it's not getting the ID of the post. What did I do wrong? Please help. Here is my code:

```
function justblog_get_attachment(){
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail('large', array('class' => 'blog-main-image'));
} else {
    // No post thumbnail, try attachments instead.
    $attachments = get_children(array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                                      'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                      'order' => 'DESC',
                                      'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));

    foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
        $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full', true);
    }
    if ($attachments) {
        echo '<img src="' . esc_url($full_img_url[0]) . '" alt="Title Image" class="blog-main-image" />';
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to populate $post using global or pass $post into the function as an argument, the former is demonstrated below

```
function justblog_get_attachment(){
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
        the_post_thumbnail('large', array('class' => 'blog-main-image'));
    } else {
        // No post thumbnail, try attachments instead.
        global $post;
        $attachments = get_children(array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                                          'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                          'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                          'order' => 'DESC',
                                          'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));

        foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
            $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full', true);
        }
        if ($attachments) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($full_img_url[0]) . '" alt="Title Image" class="blog-main-image" />';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

you could attempt this using css and a little php. Basically you modify your header code to add an additional class to your body or div wrapper around your page.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ){?>

    <div class="post-body no-feat-img">

<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="post-body">
<?php }
```

Then using this class you can target the 1st image in the post content, make the img absolute and align it to the top.

see sample here https://jsfiddle.net/1pveo2wn/1/   -- there is a button below the image to toggle the class. This is not ideal but its one method. another is to filter the post content before outputting, pull the image and display as the featured image.

One reason i won't do the code for the filter method, is I've spent the last 2 days getting around srcset and wordpress `the_post_thumbnail()` to output different sizes that fit the common container sizes for each common screen type (mobile to widescreen). Hence i think you should abandon this and just use featured image and if the user failed to select a featured image, their tough.

Comment: Hi David, I tried your fix and it returns an empty array. I am calling the function inside the WP Loop, so it should just grab the ID of the post and load the attachments from there. The post ID is showing all right! I am calling the template part inside the WP loop. Any ideas please?

Comment: you need to double check how the images are included on the post. it would be more likely post meta rather than children of the post.

Comment: I am actually new to  WordPress, still learning. I did not modify how WP adds image to the default posts (I am not dealing with custom posts here). Should the images not be children of the post by default? I am trying to fix this for three days now. When I echo the images, it loads all the images in the media library. For some weird reasons, 'post_parent' set to 'get_the_ID()/the_ID/$post->ID' doesn't bother. I am inside the loop, it should just take the post ID from the loop and load the images from that specific post, not the whole library. Please help me here. Going crazy.

Comment: no images are a seperate post really, they can be added as children using wp_insert_post, but this would be unusual. If your images in the post content thats something different altogether, its the url stored as a string and you can parse the content using preg match or similar but its a heavy process. You might be guilty of over engineering here, its relatively simple for a user to include a feat image and if none, just pull one from an images folder in your theme etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and explaining David. I am not trying anything different actually. I am adding images through WP add media button to the body of the post. When I try to echo the images, it echoes all the images in the library. My goal is to load only the images inside this post, not the whole image library. The post_parent doesn't stop loading images outside the ID of the current post. It just should. I am specifying the function to load only the images from the current post! Not the whole library. This is so frustrating.

Comment: there is a tab to change from text to code view in your editor, what is in there is the extent of the connection, i.e. it inserts the html to show the image, there is no other link. You know actually i just thought of something using css. ill update something above.